# jQuery doesn't work after updating to 1.9.1

Tags: magento-1.9

Today I updated from 1.9 to 1.9.1.
But now jQuery doesn't work any more.
Could please some one help me to find the reason for the problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jQuery file is simply not there.

```
http://happygemslondon.co.uk/skin/frontend/base/default/js/lib/jquery-1.10.2.min.js
```